# How to input Date to a Struts2 action from a jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am facing a lot of problems here in my jsp page. What tag I should use to get a date (yyyy-MM-dd) from user and store it in a Date property of a Struts2 action ?

The property in my action is declared to be of java.util.Date. I want the input from jsp page to land in this property.

please help.

I get Invalid field error (in JSP) if is use a s:textfield tag to manyally enter a date in the  right format.

Comment: I don't do Struts, so I can't give a straight answer, but any decent MVC framework should offer type conversion for any non-String values. Check this link for some hints: http://google.com/search?q=struts2+date+converter

Comment: there seems to be a problem with struts2 handling date types well. So is there any other way i can get date in a proper format and store it in date object in java

Answer (score 11):

I know this post is a bit old but a solution may be useful to others.

The default converter of Struts does not seem to work properly. The field error even occurs with readonly fields populated from the action.

I resolved it by defining my own converter:

1. Create the converter class (using the date format you need):

   ```
   public class StringToDateTimeConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter {
       // WARNING not safe in multi-threaded environments
       private static final DateFormat DATETIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

       public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] strings, Class toClass) {     
           if (strings == null || strings.length == 0 || strings[0].trim().length() == 0) {
               return null;
           }

           try {
               return DATETIME_FORMAT.parse(strings[0]);
           } catch (ParseException e) {
               throw new TypeConversionException("Unable to convert given object to date: " + strings[0]);
           }
       }

       public String convertToString(Map context, Object date) {
           if (date != null && date instanceof Date) {         
               return DATETIME_FORMAT.format(date);
           } else {
               return null;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Put the conversion annotation on the property setter (or use a conversion.properties file)

   ```
   @Conversion()
   public class MyEditAction {
       // ...

       @TypeConversion(converter="my.app.common.converter.StringToDateTimeConverter")
       public void setUploadedDate(Date uploadedDate) {
           this.uploadedDate = uploadedDate;
       }
   ```

In my case I did not need to edit it but wanted to specify the format in the jsp. 
I used an additional hidden field to keep the original value (another alternative would have been the use of Preparable interface):

```
<s:textfield name="uploadedDateDisplay" value="%{getText('format.datetimesecond',{uploadedDate})}" size="70" disabled="true"/>
<s:hidden name="uploadedDate" />
```

Comment: For the n:th time I feel compelled to add this comment: Do not use SimpleDateFormat like that. It will produce garbage when two threads use it at the same time.

Comment: @Samuel Yes. Quickest fix is to put it in a ThreadLocal. Best fix is to use another date/time framework.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved this.

```
    <s:date name="nameOfInputVal" var="formattedVal"/>
    <s:textfield name="nameOfInputVal" value="%{#formattedVal}" key="labelkey" />
```

And in your message properties a key/value:

```
struts.date.format=dd/MM/yyyy
```

Which indicates the default format and you don't have to write it in each date tag.

Hope this helps

Comment: or more straightforward : <s:textfield name="mydate" value="%{getText('format.date',{mydate})}" />. But that doesn't solve the problem of parsing the date into a Date fied in your action !

Comment: I agree with Pierre, when you send the form, the input is String and then Struts 2 converts the String to Date, but the question is: Where does Struts 2 configure the default format for this conversion?

Comment: @DavidGarcíaGonzález that's a conversion that must be done using a converter. http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html

Comment: More straightforward:
`<s:date name="myDateField" var="dd" format="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" />` then 
`<s:textfield name="myDateField" value="%{dd}">`

Answer (score 1):

So maybe I don't understand the question. But I hope this example helps (btw this code will not work its just to help give you an idea of how it sturts2 works its magic); So for form input you need to have a holder class in java, so you can call your date from your action class such as Holder.java:

```
public class Holder{
  pirvate Date date; 
  public getDate(){
     return date; 
  }
  public setDate(Date date){
    this.date = date; 
  }
}
```

Your Holder.java validation so you can make sure its a date Holder-validation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 
1.0.2//EN" "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="date">
    <field-validator type="date">
               <message><![CDATA[ Must be a date ]]></message>
    </field-validator>
     </field>
</validators>
```

Your action class where you call your make sure holder.getdate to get your date getDateAction.java:

```
private Holder holder;
    public class getDateAction{
    public String execute(){
     //get your date
      Date date = holder.getDate(); 

       return SUCCESS; 
     }
    }
```

Your jsp form where you give the client the ability to input the date. Make sure for input name="holder.date". Here is site.jsp:

```
<s:form id="Form" name="MyForm" action="getDateAction" method="post"  class="form">
<input type="text" name="holder.date" id="date" size="25" value="" class="required text">
</s:form>
```

and last but not least your struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<package name="example" extends="struts-default">
<action name="getdate" class="com.location.action.getDateAction">
         <result>example.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

---

There is an explanation of Struts2 date Format here at: [Struts 2 Date Format Examples](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/date/struts-2-date-format.shtml)

But I believe the tag you are looking for in jsp is

```
<s:date name="Date_Name" format="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```

Where Date_Name is the Date object in Java.

Comment: The s:date tag is for outputting java.lang.Date values in various formats, not for form input.

Answer (score 0):

the `<s:date />` tag only displays dates - it doesn't provide input.

I don't believe Struts provides out of the box date input, unless you use the date time picker, which is an dojo / javascript tag.  More info on that is here: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/datetimepicker.html

If you don't go down that route, you will most likely need to map the date on your JSP to a string, then format it in your action class.  You can make this easier by getting Struts to validate the value first.

Answer (score 0):

**jsp:**

```
<s:textfield name="date" id="date" key="invitation.date" required="true" value="%{getText('format.date',{date})}" size="8"/>
```

**?.properties**

```
format.date={0,date,dd/MM/yyyy}
```

**Action.java**

```
import java.util.Date;
private Date date;
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

**script:**
You can add jquery.datepicker (I don't recommend struts datepicker):
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
$("#date").datepicker({dateFormat: dateFormat});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Date date;

public void setDate(String date) {
//setter method param type is String
    try {
        this.date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


<form action="target.do">
    <input name="date" value="2015-5-28">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Creating `SimpleDateFormat` each time getter is accessed is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution which i tried and it worked :)
1)Keep the column in which you want to store date in database's table in "DATE" data type only.
2)Use only Textfield tag in JSP page.Dont use Date tag.
**Note**:Make sure that you make user input date in YYYY-MM-DD format only by placing a placeholder in textfield tag !
3)Keep the variable for accessing that field of string type only.Dont use DATE data type.
4)Now run Query: **Select DATE_FORMAT(datecolumnname,'%d/%m%/Y') as date_two from tablename;** and you will get date from that columnin dd/mm/yyyy format even if it is stored in YYYY-MM-DD format in table .
5)And you can also compare your datecolumn's data with curdate() and related functions as well and it works :) .
6)Like i used query: **Select id,name,DATE_FORMAT(datecolumnname,'%d/%m/%Y') as datecolumn2 from tablename where datecolumnname >= curdate();**