# struts2 date can not get time by jquery datetimepicker

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, datepicker

Im new in struts2 , and created a small web application, i want to a post is timer and i choose jquery datetimpicker, after user choose time and date ,it will dislay in time and date that user chosen.

i use this jquery

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tengcalendar.shtml

my problem is, in action of struts2 it can get date but time it return is 00:00:00

exactly the result is :

```
Tue Nov 20 00:00:00 ICT 2012
```

and my action class is:

```
public class Foo extends ActionSupport{
    private Date fooDate;

     //getter - setter;
}
```

and my form is:

```
//form ....
<s:textfield name="fooDate" id="dateReleased" 
             cssClass="mws-textinput"  cssStyle="width:80%" />
<a href="javascript:NewCal('dateReleased','ddmmyyyy',true,12)">
      <img src="js/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" 
           border="0" alt="Pick a date">   
</a>
```

when i choose 2012-11-20 5:40:10PM

and in action class i just got

```
Tue Nov 20 00:00:00 ICT 2012
```

But i want

```
Tue Nov 20 5:40:10 PM ICT 2012
```

how can i do it?

Comment: What type your `fooDate` is?

Comment: oh sorry this is my fail i was edit it, fooDate type Date !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Struts2 uses "short format for the Locale associated with the current request" to parse dates. Use `String` for you `fooDate` and convert to date in methods where you need it or create type converter for `Date` http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397498/how-to-input-date-to-a-struts2-action-from-a-jsp  i following this post but it till not work, i got NoSuchMethodException , i use @TypeConversion for pojo class and @Conversion() at my action , but i till get error

Comment: Creation of type converter is another question. I have provided you with an answer and a link about type conversion.

Answer (score 1):

And that Calendar is not jQuery, just javascript, pretty ugly.

This is the real jQuery DatePicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

And there are currently a couple of customization of it to add the Time too:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

http://umcdatetimepicker.codeplex.com/

or the standalone TimePicker: http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/

Eye-Candy for the win.