# Input Date to Struts2 in JSP

Tags: java, struts2

I'm using Struts2 with Hibernate ORM. I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397498/how-to-input-date-to-a-struts2-action-from-a-jsp) question that I have to create a converter and register my bean `Date` property with that converter. I have tried something else like:

```
private Date myDate;
private SimpleDateConverter format = new SimpleDateConverter("MM/dd/yyyy");

public String getMyDate()
{
    return myDate.toString();
}

public setMyDate(String myDate)
{
    try{
        this.myDate = format.parse(myDate);
    } Catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. Can someone explain me why? Since my code above can do the convert fine

Comment: what you mean by it does not work? need more explanation

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi it throws a conversion exception when I tried to open it, but I fixed it according to Kevin Bowersox suggest. Thank for your attention, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code returns the class in the `getter` by using the default implementation of `toString` it should be formatted using the formatter.

```
public String getMyDate()
{
    return format.format(myDate);
}
```

There is also a casing issue in this part of the code:

```
public setMyDate(String myDate)
{
    try{
        this.MyDate = format.parse(myDate); //should be this.myDate = ...
    } Catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried as your suggest and got this error `Exception thrown by getter for property myDate of bean customer` when open run the jsp file

Comment: See the update, also make sure your setting the date, before getting it.

Comment: Solved. I changed as you suggested still have error so I changed `<html:text />` to `<input type="text" />` and it work fine. Thank you very much, sir. But would you please explain me why `<html:text />` doesn't work but `<input type="text" />` works?

Comment: @Doan Cuong, I'm not quite sure why the struts tag would not work given my limited view of the problem, it could be the struts config or that Struts was not wiring the bean properly.

Comment: The reason is: `<html:text />` is **not** a `Struts2 tag`. It is a `Struts1 tag`, that you are probably using with the `Struts1 plugin`. Please, don't :)